# Problemas con la instrucción COPY en Docker usando Dockerfile

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, docker

Intento crear una imagen de un contenedor mysql, pero me daba un error de autenticación de plugin, lo he solventado mirando en este enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded .

La solución valida para mi es la que tiene 76 votos. El caso es que intento sobreescribir my.cnf con uno en el que añado lo que comentan como solución: **default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password** ,y al arrancar el dockerfile me dice el siguiente error:

> Step 2/3 : COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
>   COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder204357196/my.cnf: no such file or directory

**Mi archivo my.cnf:**

```
# Copyright (c) 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301 USA

#
# The MySQL  Server configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv= NULL
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Custom config should go here
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

**Mi archivo Dockerfile:**

```
# Indicates that the mysql image will be used as the base image.
FROM mysql

#Try copy my.cnf on this path /etc/mysql/
COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf

#Try only to restart mysql (not container)
RUN service mysql restart
```

**Mi estructura de carpetas:**
Tengo una carpeta llamada build_docker desde donde ejecuto build y dentro los archivos Dcokerfile y my.cnf al mismo nivel.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda!!

Comment: Al ejecutar docker build dentro de la ruta, el comando COPY funciona con docker build . y no con docker build - < Dockerfile.

Comment: lo que pusiste como respuesta no parece una respuesta sino un comentario. Deberías publicarlo como respuesta indicando cómo resolviste el problema claramente. Lee [answer] para más información.